# How can I get results of a meta_value with "order by ASC" date in a postmeta value?

Tags: php, wordpress, post-meta

````
```
````

0. table = postmeta
1. post_id = '1521';
2. meta_key = 'store_data';
3. meta_value = 'holiday_dates';
4. s:16:"holiday_dates";a:9:{i:12396;s:10:"2021/04/13";i:535943;s:10:"2021/04/14";i:271520;s:10:"2021/04/15";i:804617;s:10:"2021/04/21";i:515516;s:10:"2021/04/30";i:476758;s:10:"2021/04/19";i:355992;s:10:"2021/04/28";i:862607;s:10:"2021/05/17";i:616642;s:10:"2021/05/12";

Comment: in your sample `meta_value` is a string, how do you want to get in any order?

Comment: Hi, it's not possible?   What I have is $holiday_dates = get_post_meta(1521,'holiday_dates');

Comment: TBH I have even no idea what your problem is you show us some portions of your data, without code and explaining what exactly you want achieve, fix your question if you want to get any valuable help.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, works for me.

$holiday_dates = get_post_meta(1521,'holiday_dates');

sort($holiday_dates);

sort() - sort arrays in ascending order

rsort() - sort arrays in descending order